# CSS on BODY - changes not taking affect?

Tags: asp.net, css, themes

body
    {
     font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
     font-size: xx-small;
     color: #008080;
    }

on the top of my style sheet, and non of those specs are taking affect on my page, nothing, i tried doing it on td, table, tr, span, div just in case i needed to be more specific, but nothing is working, i want to make global changes without having to change things one by one and i can't seem to find a solution, any ideas?

thanks - your input is appreciated

ps: more info for those interested:
i have a standard mster page, and content pages, listview control that populated data from a database, but all the elements in my controls of concern is html elements (im sure some would be runat="server") the style is linked correctly as well, as other styles on the style sheet work...

here is the code where the text is not changing..

HTML TAGS ARENT DISPLAYING IN MY COMMENTS FOR SOME REASON...???

Comment: Can you post example code because it works perfectly as expected for me

Comment: definitely use firefox w firebug and you will see *exactly* why text is being rendered as it is ..

Comment: <ItemTemplate>
<tr><td style="background-color: #ECEFF5"> 
<table width="100%"><tr><td align="left">
<asp:Label ID="UsernameLabel" runat="server" Text="default"/>
</td><td align="right">
<asp:Label ID="DateAddedLabel" runat="server" Text='DATABINDING TEXT HERE' />
</td></tr></table>
</td></tr>
<tr><td align="left" style="background-color: #F2F2F2">
<asp:Label ID="CommentLabel" runat="server" Text='DATABINDING TEXT HERE' />
</td></tr>
</ItemTemplate>

Comment: OMG, REVELATION!!!
it works in firefox, but not in internet explorer, it is running off my local host, so can't be a temporary internet files problem, what the ??? how??? any ideas?

Comment: CLEARED TEMP INTERNET FILES, AND IT WORKED, EVEN THO I WAS RUNNIN GOFF LOCALHOST, STILL KEEPING TEMP INTERNET FILES

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear your temporary files and try restarting the browser - chances are that its using a chached copy of the page.

Comment: i will do that now, just in case, didnt think it would be a temp files problem sinc ei am running off localhost, but it works perfectly in firefox, just not in ie!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, the browser doesn't care where the content is coming from. All it knows is that it should cache pages to speed up browsing. Your computer and my computer are the same to your browser(s) in that respect. Once, agian - you're welcome and Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing syntactically wrong with that code. The issue must have something to do with how it is being applied to the HTML (and thus with some code or HTTP response header that you haven't shared with us).

Comment: i'll provide anything you ask me to, let me know, i have a standard mster page, and content pages, listview control that populated data from a database, but all the elements in my controls of concern is html elements (im sure some would be runat="server") the style is linked correctly as well, as other styles on the style sheet work...

<link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing the html and style sheet, but perhaps later declared styles are "overwriting" your body style?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see these changes they are being overridden by other styling applied somewhere else.

The easiest way to debug what css rules are being applied to elements on your page is by using a tool like the firebug extension available for firefox (available from http://getfirebug.com/)

Once you have this you can select an element and see what has been applied by what rule - and then you can override that rule!

There is also an IE dev toolbar, and developer extensions for chrome and firefox that do the same thing.

Hope that helps.